# Can My University See Through my VPN on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, vpn, privacy

So to use the internet at my university, you have to accept a certificate and log in with your username and password. I use a VPN and an iPhone on iOS 16.

I haven't had to trust the certificate in a while and could not find any profiles downloaded on my iphone.  A few additional stats regarding the certificate I have to "trust" to access the internet:

It was issued by AD Enterprise Root CA

The algorithm listed in the public key was RSA Encryption. Usage was listed as digital signature, key encipherment. Extended key usage had the purpose of both server and client authentication. Based on that information, it seems the purpose of the certificate isn't to decrypt my information, rather it is to keep it secure. Basically, I wonder if the usage was to decrypt HTTPS it would be listed in the certificate information or is this a situation where people need to learn the details of what trusting a cert compromises on the security front.

Can my university see my web traffic and know which sites I visit?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to have nothing to do with Apple Hardware or software

Comment: The certificate you accepted is for connecting to their Wi-Fi it doesn't effect your VPN. That being said, don't do illegal stuff with other people's internet.

Comment: Thanks for the information Ezekiel! I'm sorry mmmmmmm, I should have mentioned I am referring to my iPhone accepting the certificate. Boom, Apple! But in all honesty if you think the post should be closed feel free. Ezekiel has helped me out plenty.

Comment: I've edited this so it's on topic. Please post an answer someone in the answer section below.

Comment: Thanks for the edit bmike! Also Ezekiel, I have no plans on doing illegal things on the wifi. I am just overtly paranoid about things :)